# Como fazer para executar uma rotina web dentro do tkinter sem travar o mainloop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aplicação-web, tkinter

Bom dia criei uma aplicação pelo Tkinter e agora estou tentando disponibilizar as informações pela web aos usuários em tempo real. O problema é que a função app.run não deixa executar o mainloop. Teria outra forma de fazer?

```
#Rotina Principal
#=============================================================================

janela = Tk()
janela.geometry ('1480x650')
janela.title('Sistema de Classificação de Defeitos')

quadro01 = Frame (janela, width = 1680, height = 600,relief = 'raise', bd = 10)
quadro01.pack(side = TOP)

quadro01a = Frame (janela, width = 1680, height = 300,relief = 'raise', bd = 10)
quadro01a.pack(side = BOTTOM)

quadro01b = Frame (quadro01, relief = 'raise')
quadro01b.pack()

quadro02 = Frame (janela, width = 700, height = 500,relief = 'raise', bg = 'yellow', bd = 8)
quadro02.pack(side = LEFT)

quadro03 = Frame (quadro02, width = 500, height = 1000,relief = 'raise', bg = 'yellow', bd = 8)
quadro03.pack()

quadro04 = Frame (janela, width = 700, height = 500,relief = 'raise', bg = 'purple', bd = 8)
quadro04.pack(side = LEFT)

quadro05 = Frame (quadro04, width = 500, height = 300,relief = 'raise', bg = 'purple', bd = 8)
quadro05.pack()

texto01 = Label (quadro01, text = variaveis_rotina['msg'], font = 'Arial 36 bold',fg = 'blue', width = 48)
texto01.pack(side = TOP)

texto02 = Label (quadro03, text = variaveis_rotina['area'], font = 'Arial 100 bold', bg = 'yellow', fg = 'purple', width = 8)
texto02.pack()

texto03 = Label (quadro05, text = variaveis_rotina['defeito'], font = 'Arial 100 bold', bg = 'purple', fg = 'yellow', width = 8)
texto03.pack()

b1 = Button (quadro01, text = variaveis_rotina['msg_button'], font = 'Arial 24 bold',bg = 'blue', fg = 'yellow',command = proximo)
b1.pack(side = RIGHT)

if (variaveis_rotina['passo'] == 0 or variaveis_rotina['passo'] == 30) :
    b2 = Button (quadro01, text = 'Não', font = 'Arial 24 bold',bg = 'blue', fg = 'yellow',command = sair)
    b2.pack(side = LEFT)

texto01a = Label (quadro01a, text = 'Contagem: ' + str (variaveis_rotina['contCourosGeral']), font = 'Arial 20 bold',fg = 'blue', width = 48)
texto01a.pack(side = LEFT)

texto01b = Label (quadro01a, text = 'Couros avaliados: ' + str (variaveis_rotina['contCourosAvaliados']), font = 'Arial 20 bold',fg = 'blue', width = 48)
texto01b.pack(side = RIGHT)
#========================================================
# Inseri essa parte para disponibilizar algumas informações pela web ainda estou testando mas percebi que app.run não deixa executar o mainloop e por consequencia não entra na tela principal
app = Flask (__name__)

@app.route ('/')

def inicio () :
    global variaveis_rotina
    return render_template ('Inicio.html', msg = 'A contagem é ' + str (variaveis_rotina['contCourosGeral']) )

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    print ("Servidor: " + subprocess.getoutput('hostname -I').strip() + ":5000")
    app.run(debug = True, host = '192.168.1.10') # essa linha parece que entra em outro loop e não deixa executar o mainloop
#=================================================================

janela.mainloop()
```

Comment: E por que não faz isso em arquivos diferentes, com processos diferentes, com as informações que deseja disponibilizar persistidas no banco de dados? E leia sobre threads...

Answer (score 0):

Utilize `threads` para rodar processos paralelamente. Veja esse exemplo:

```
from threading import Thread

# Seu código...

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    print ("Servidor: " + subprocess.getoutput('hostname -I').strip() + ":5000")
    Thread(target=lambda:app.run(debug = True, host = '192.168.1.10')).start()
#=================================================================

janela.mainloop()
```

O que threads fazem é executar várias tarefas ao mesmo tempo. Dessa forma não é necessário esperar acabar a execução do `app.run` para finalmente abrir o `mainloop`.

É importante avisar que em algumas funções ou métodos, threads podem acabar gerando problemas. Esses problemas são causados na maioria das vezes, porque o método que você deseja executar (por exemplo o método `Icon.run` de `pystray`) necessita que a execução seja feita no main thread. Estou dizendo isto pois não conheço o `Flask` mas vale a pena tentar usar `Thread`.